# How can I make this AWK command case-insensitive?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

I am trying to print occurrences of a field in a .csv file only using an awk command. For example in a file test.csv like so:

```
layla;rebel;TAT
han_solo;rebel;TAT
darth_vader;empire;DKS
yoda;rebel;TAT
```

with the command:

```
cat test.csv | ./how_many_are_we.sh dks
```

I wish to have the following output:

```
1
```

Here is my code in how_many_are_we.sh (which is working but case-sensitive):

```
#! /bin/bash
awk -F ";" -v location=$1 'BEGIN {count=0;} { if ($3 == location) count+=1} END {print count}'
```

I tried adding `IGNORECASE=1` in different places but I can't seem to find the right way to make it work.

Excuse my bad wording, and thank you for the help.

Comment: `IGNORECASE` is gawk-specific, are you sure you're running gawk?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could change the case of entered value and for 3rd field to lower case and then compare their values to make sure however they are entered comparison shouldn't be affected.

```
#!/bin/bash
awk -F ";" -v location="$1" 'BEGIN {location=tolower(location);count=0;} { if (tolower($3) == location) count+=1} END {print count+0}' Input_file
```

OR As per Glenn sir's comments use shell trick to make it lowercase in variable itself.

```
#!/bin/bash
awk -v location="${1,,}" 'BEGIN{FS=";"} (tolower($3) == location){count+=1} END{print count+0}' Input_file
```

---

---

OR more `awk`sh way change `awk` command to following(above is OP's command fix this is to make it `awk`sh style)

`awk -v location="$1" 'BEGIN{location=tolower(location);FS=";"} (tolower($3) == location){count+=1} END{print count+0}'`

---

***NOTE:*** For using `IGNORECASE=1`, you should mention it either in `BEGIN` section like `BEGIN{IGNORECASE=1}` OR like an `awk` variable `-v IGNORECASE="1"`.

Also on a side note, OP's shebang is having spaces between `#!` and `/bin/bash` which shouldn't be the case so I had fixed that too here.

Comment: Thank you for the speedy response. This works!
I'm still wondering why IGNORECASE=1 wasn't working, is it specific to gawk or was I just misplacing it?

Comment: @Odil, Sorry you have updated your comment so replying it here now, I have mentioned in my solution how to use `IGNORECASE` ideal scenario so please make sure you are using that way only.

Comment: I'd recommend `-v location="${1,,}"` to lowercase the input argument. That saves you from having to `tolower(location)` for each line.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 thanks for pointing out the shebang mistake, I didn't know about that.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, if you have a script that can work easily on lower-case input, you can convert the input stream with `tr`, so it can also manipulate mixed-case input.

```
$ command | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' | ./script
```

However, if you want to mask the `tr`, you can embed it into your script by default using the following redirection:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
exec 0< <( tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' )
# the rest of your script comes here:
awk '...'
```

which now allows you to do something like:

```
$ command | ./script
```